# how can i do this url (ca.mysite.com) on codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting, subdomain

i am making a site, that will be used for posting ads listings like backpage or craigslist,

now I'm having a problem with URLs, because for now it is available only in US cities,

for example: `www.mysite.com/birmingham/` and this one i got it fine, every US cities url will be like this `www.mysite.com/city`

now i want it to be available in international countries,
and im having a problem now with my URLs, for example Toronto, i want the URLs to be like `ca.mysite.com/toronto` because Toronto is in Canada i don't have an idea on how to do it, sorry im just new in codeigniter

thank you hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi just replace following code wiht $config['base_url'] in your application/config/config.php

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
{
    $config['base_url'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
    $config['base_url'] .= '://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
}

else
{
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
}
```

no need to put any thing htaccess file

Comment: thanks for the answer, hmm how does this work? do i need to setup anything?, i just want my url to be like a subdomain (ca.mysite.com/city) when it is international cities, but if its inside US it will only be www.mysite.com/city, ive tried this one but i dont have an idea on how it works, thanks

Comment: this will work really great i have use this code for one of my project where every college has its own subdomain, this is example of main site www.uni.com, IT College has it.uni.com, Business College has ba.uni.com. you can try same code on  your localhost with different virtual host

Comment: how do you do it in virtual host? how you will you do the subdomain? thanks again

Comment: well in your case no need virtual host, if you are using windows OS just edit your hosts file its show you 127.0.0.1       localhost under it put 127.0.0.1       ca.localhost and save in case of Mac OS try this small app to edit host file http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/40003/hosts

Comment: hmm ive done all those parts i did ca.mysite.com and i am getting forbidden 403 errors, hmmm, do i need to install another codeigniter inside the /root?

Comment: no need to install anything new your just old ci installation will work localhost/your_project, test.localhost/your_project will work same

Answer (score 0):

use this htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://$1.mysite.com [L,R=301]
```

now you can access any country. like for Canada

```
ca.mysite.com
```

Comment: That is one part of the story. Please also mention that they have setup a Catch All DNS entry for that domain, or atleast add all the country named subdomains in DNS that they wish to process